# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl is not defined in Visual Studio 2010, even though objects of this type are created automatically by ClassWizard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am creating a dialog application in Visual Studio 2010.  I have added an MFC `EditBrowse` control from the Toolbox in the dialog editor.  I have then right-clicked and "Added Variable", accepting the defaults with the ClassWizard.

The ClassWizard automatically creates a new member of my Dialog class, of type `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`.  Also, this class is correctly added to the `DoDataExchange()` function, and seems to be set up properly.

However, the compiler complains that `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` is undefined.

The following header file has automatically been included:

```
#include "afxcmn.h"
```

Should I add another `#include`, or is there a deeper issue here?

Comment: Thank you for the question !!!!! Been searching for 30 minutes already !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx) it is defined in `afxeditbrowsectrl.h`.

Comment: Note that you also need to derive the main class from `CWinAppEx`, instead of `CWinApp` (in stdafx.h, `#include "afxwinappex.h"`), and then call `InitShellManager()` from `InitInstance()`.  I have no idea why this isn't done by default with AppWizard for an MFC application - perhaps it's because my project is actually a BCGSoft application.